# LINQ .OrderBy single letter then by another letter

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, lambda

Im trying to make a special orderby with Linq.
It has to order by S then P then NB then V and then NC.
Im not sure if its the best way to de this but this is what i have:

```
repeater.DataSource = query.OrderBy(p => p.Title ?).ThenBy(?).ThenBy(?);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "order by S then P then NB then V and then NC"?

Comment: It has to order by specific letters, the rest is alphabetic

Comment: Post us please the incoming query example, and what you want at output.

Comment: var query = from p in dc.Products select p; output i want my "products" sorted by the letters i that specific arrangement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only have those distinct values in the field, then you can just use a dictionary to translate the strings into suitable numbers, like this:

```
var order = new Dictionary<string, int>();
order.Add("S", 0);
order.Add("P", 1);
order.Add("NB", 2);
order.Add("V", 3);
order.Add("Nc", 4);
repeater.DataSource = query.OrderBy(p => order[p.Title]);
```

If the source is LINQ to SQL, you would have to realise it into a list first, so that you are using LINQ to Objects to do the sorting:

```
repeater.DataSource = query.ToList().OrderBy(p => order[p.Title]);
```

Comment: +1 for the great solution. But what if what if key is not present in the dictionary? I have 2 types of sizes, i.e. for t-shirts small, medium etc, but i also have shoes, 6, 6.5 etc i want to sort the small to xl in the dictionary but the numbers from low to high. do i need to include all the shoes sizes in the dictionary?

Comment: @edgarpetrauskas: You can use an expression that checks the dictionary and has alternative code for other cases, something like: `.OrderBy(p => order.HasKey(p.Size) ? order[p.Size] : p.Size)`

Answer (score 4):

You should use `OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>, IComparer<TKey>)` signature and write your own comparer for this case.

Comment: and im still blank - could you write an example or give a little more guidance?

Comment: Note that this will not work when dealing with LINQ to Expression trees (LINQ to SQL, LINQ to Entities, NHibernate LINQ, etc). Still +1.

Answer (score 1):

```
query.OrderBy(p => p.Title, new MySpecialComparer());

public class MySpecialComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    private static Dictionary<string, int> parser = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    static MySpecialComparer()
    {
      parser.Add("S", 0);
      parser.Add("P", 1);
      parser.Add("NB", 2);
      parser.Add("V", 3);
      parser.Add("NC", 4);
    }


    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return parser[x] - parser[y];
    }
}
```

Comment: This gives me a "Unsupported overload used for query operator 'OrderBy'."

Comment: @Buckley: It works for me. Are you using Linq to SQL? What is the type of `query`?

Comment: Its Linq to Sql yes and query is just a normal query like: var query = from p in dc.Products select p;

Comment: @Buckley: I'm afraid `IComparer` won't work for an SQL query. Try what `Guffa` suggested.